# .NET: Write all values to string, in order, from nested XML structure

Tags: c#, .net, xml

*Note: My final solution is posted at the bottom of this post.*

I'm trying to build a string containing all of the field/messages contained in an XML object such that the resulting string needs to someone retain structure information of the errors.

My problem is the structure can be nested. I struggle to select only one level/descendant down without selecting all elements named "field" or "Error". I do not know linq-xml well enough to grab the first, check what children nodes are present, and continue from there.

The structure of the object is as follows:

```
<PingResponse>
    <Status>denied</Status>
    <Errors>
        <Error>
            <Field>lead</Field>
            <Errors>
                <Error>
                    <Field>drivers</Field>
                    <Errors>
                        <Error>
                            <Field>gender</Field>
                            <Message>This field is required.</Message>
                        </Error>
                        <Error>
                            <Field>license_status</Field>
                            <Message>This field is required.</Message>
                        </Error>
                        <Error>
                            <Field>relationship</Field>
                            <Message>This field is required.</Message>
                        </Error>
                    </Errors>
                </Error>
            </Errors>
        </Error>
    </Errors>
</PingResponse>
```

In this example, I would want to produce the resulting string:

```
String errors = "Field: lead Field: drivers Field: gender Message: This field is required. Field: license_status Message: This field is required Field: relationship Message: This field is required"
```

**Notes:**

*Errors* will always contain at least one error element.

*Error* Can contain :

1) *Field* + *Errors* OR

2) *Field* + *Message*, children.

My plan to solve this was:

```
protected string errorDecoder(XElement node)
{
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

// PseudoCode     
// 1) Check nodes within element 
// 2) If "Field" or "Message" present, append those values to **sb** 
// 3) If "Errors" present, call this method with this node, to finish building string through recursion. 
// 4) Ultimately return the final string when all elements have been processed

returns string;
}
```

I've been unable to figure out how to read/return only 1 level deep of descendants. When trying to select decendants by name, ALL fields with that name. If I try to select the first instance of an element, I may inadvertently jump too far down the tree.

How can I:

1) Check what next level children exists

2) And how to grab the values of only the next level of children only, so that i can build my message out like I want?

Or your ideas on a solution that produces the same result.

**MY Final Solution:**
I discovered my biggest issue was understanding LINQ query. Once I figured out I should just query for the "Field" element alone, everything worked out nicely. I retrieve both the *field* value and the *message* value, if the elements are present. Thanks to everyone for your help!

```
StringBuilder responseReason = new StringBuilder("Denied: ");
var errorCollection =  XDocument.Parse(result)
                                .Descendants()
                                .Where(x => x.Element("Field") != null);

foreach (var error in errorCollection)
{
    responseReason.Append(" Field: " + error.Element("Field").Value.ToString());
    responseReason.Append(error.Element("Message") != null ? " Message: " + error.Element("Message").Value.ToString() : "");
}

response = responseReason.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Descendants`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.descendants.aspx) matches all levels of descendants.

You need to use [`Elements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.elements.aspx) in order to get the direct child nodes, which gives you your "the next level of children only".

To find what next level has such children - you will need to find if such children exist (using `Descendants`) and possibly use `Parent` of each node till you get back to the current node (this is one possible algorithm, not sure how preformant it is). This should give you depth information.

Comment: I initially confused how descendants works when querying with LINQ. I found the simplest way was to grab all elements containing "Field" element, and only look for Message elements. Looping through allows me to ultimately unwind all field/messages in order.

Answer (score 0):

While for the most part the nesting levels in your XML file introduce an order, there's no order given in the section of the file quoted below. Even though most XML parsers *should* return them in the order provided in the file, this is not a requirement made by the XML standard and any XML parser is free to return the following `<Error>` blocks in any order:

```
<Errors>
    <Error>
        <Field>gender</Field>
        <Message>This field is required.</Message>
    </Error>
    <Error>
        <Field>license_status</Field>
        <Message>This field is required.</Message>
    </Error>
    <Error>
        <Field>relationship</Field>
        <Message>This field is required.</Message>
    </Error>
</Errors>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will produce what you're asking for:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

string errors =
    (
        from e in doc.Descendants("Error")
        let field = (string)e.Element("Field")
        let message = (string)e.Element("Message")
        where field != null
        select new { field, message }
    ).Aggregate(
        new StringBuilder(),
        (sb, o) => (sb.Length == 0 ? sb : sb.Append(' ')).AppendFormat(
            o.message != null ? "Field: {0} Message: {1}" : "Field: {0}",
            o.field,
            o.message),
        sb => sb.ToString());
```